# Extract hours and minutes from a timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have this pandas data frame and need to extract hrs and minutes from the time column AND keep it in time type so I can run math opertions on those points.

I've used this pd.to_datetime method and it does the trick but returns the time in 'object' type.

```py
df_SRS['Time_of_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df_SRS['time'], errors='coerce').dt.time.dropna()
```

I can't use it for math operations e.g. > or < comparisons.

How do I get proper time numbers?

[image]

Comment: Please post examples as text, not image. Also note that pandas only has a datetime type built-in, no time type. if you call for `.dt.time` you get vanilly Python time objects.

Comment: In general, you're probably looking for [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) - that way, you don't have to create any new columns from your original 'time' column.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helping

```
DF["Day"] = pd.to_datetime(DF["date"]).dt.day
DF["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(DF["date"]).dt.month
DF["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(DF["date"]).dt.year

for example
DF['Month'] = [i<5 for i in DF['Month']]
DF
```

Now you can do some math operations...